# Collections code involving mutable.IndexedSeq, view, take, and grouped throws ClassCastException

Tags: scala, casting, scala-collections

The following scala code compiles fine.

```
object Main extends App {
  import scala.collection.mutable.IndexedSeq

  def doIt() {
    val nums: IndexedSeq[Int] = Array(3,5,9,11)
    val view: IndexedSeq[Int] = nums.view
    val half: IndexedSeq[Int] = view.take(2)
    val grouped: Iterator[IndexedSeq[Int]] = half.grouped(2)
    val firstPair: IndexedSeq[Int] = grouped.next() //throws exception here
  }

  doIt()
}
```

However, at runtime it thows `java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.SeqViewLike$$anon$1 cannot be cast to scala.collection.mutable.IndexedSeq`
on the call `grouped.next()`

I would expect the call to `grouped.next()` to return something equal to `IndexedSeq[Int](3,5)`

I am wondering why is this code failing, and if there a proper way to fix it?

If I repeat the same steps in the REPL, the type information confirms why the code compiles, but does not give me any insight to why the exception was thrown:

```
scala> val nums = Array(3,5,9,11)
nums: Array[Int] = Array(3, 5, 9, 11)

scala> val view = nums.view
view: scala.collection.mutable.IndexedSeqView[Int,Array[Int]] = SeqView(...)

scala> val half = view.take(2)
half: scala.collection.mutable.IndexedSeqView[Int,Array[Int]] = SeqViewS(...)

scala> val grouped = half.grouped(2)
grouped: Iterator[scala.collection.mutable.IndexedSeqView[Int,Array[Int]]] = non-empty iterator

scala> val firstPair = grouped.next()
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.SeqViewLike$$anon$1 cannot be cast to scala.collection.mutable.IndexedSeqView
```

Scala version 2.10.0-20121205-235900-18481cef9b -- Copyright 2002-2012, LAMP/EPFL

Comment: reproducible with Scala 2.10.0 final

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you ran into [bug SI-6709](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6709)

Comment: Thanks for finding the bug report and adding the relevant info from my situation to it.